# Entity type field in form, with empty choices

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

My goal is to create a form, that has an entity type field with empty choices be created with values retrieved from ajax calls.

I have a Form called, `IngredientType` which represents the `Ingredient` entity. It has a Many To Many relationship with the `Recipe` entity, resulting in a new entity called `IngredientInRecipe`. That entity also has some extra values on it. The `ingredientInRecipe` field in the `RecipeType` form is a `CollectionType`.

The `ingredient` field in the `IngredientInRecipeType` form looks like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('ingredient', EntityType::class, [
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'choice_value' => 'uuid',
        'class' => Ingredient::class,
        'choices' => [],
        'mapped' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'ingredient-select'
        ]
    ])
```

Note that since the `id` is not returned in the ajax call (data protection) I have to rely on the `uuid` field of the entity. Also, the `'choices'` is empty. This is done because we can have thousands of ingredients, and tens of ingredients in each recipe, having 10, 20 or 30 inputs, each with more than a thousands values is just stupid.

Now this gives me the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[ingredientRecipe].children[0].children[ingredient] = e29b7bcc-aa20-415e-a383-c49cd6bdc01d

Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Unable to reverse value for property path "ingredient": The choice "e29b7bcc-aa20-415e-a383-c49cd6bdc01d" does not exist or is not unique

Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
The choice "e29b7bcc-aa20-415e-a383-c49cd6bdc01d" does not exist or is not unique
```

So, as you can see I have added `'mapped'` and `'by_reference'` with false values, hoping that was the cause, and then I could find the values manually in the controller, same error received, so that was not the problem.

I tried adding a `DataTransformer` so that `uuid` to `Ingredient` gets transformed. That was triggered and functions were called, but it looks like the form transformation happens earlier in the event chain.

Then I tried messing with the form itself, thinking that it can't transform because the option is not in the choices array. Which led me to the following attempt.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $formEvent) {
    $formData = $formEvent->getData();
    $uuid = $formData['ingredient'];
    $form = $formEvent->getForm();
    $form->remove('ingredient');
    $ingredient = $this->manager->getRepository(Ingredient::class)->findOneBy(['uuid' => $uuid]);

    $form->add('ingredient', EntityType::class, [
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'class' => Ingredient::class,
        'choices' => [$ingredient->getUuid() => $ingredient],
        'mapped' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'ingredient-select'
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Not really clean code, but the functionality is there. This too gives me the same error. I know this code runs, and I know that I have the correct values in the choices now since when I inspect the symfony profiler (such an awesome tool btw) I can see this

```
[
    e29b7bcc-aa20-415e-a383-c49cd6bdc01d => Object(AppBundle\Entity\Ingredient)
]
```

But it still says

```
The choice "e29b7bcc-aa20-415e-a383-c49cd6bdc01d" does not exist or is not unique
```

So I am thinking, is it something else? Is there anyone who can help with this?

Comment: did you ever find a good solution to this? I'm struggling with the same.